# How to create CloudWatch logs trigger for AWS Lambda function using aws SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#putSubscriptionFilter-property

nodejs

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config = new AWS.Config
    ({
        accessKeyId: "AKIA******",
        secretAccessKey: "6RJf******vy",
    });
const cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({ region: 'a******1' });

var params = {
    destinationArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:******:function:******', 
    filterName: 'LambdaStream_******', 
    filterPattern: '?Error ?Waring ?error ?"node(1)" ?info ?INFO', 
    logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/******', 
    distribution: 'ByLogStream',
};
cloudwatchlogs.putSubscriptionFilter(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log( err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

I will get the following error:

```
 { InvalidParameterException: Could not execute the lambda function. Make sure you have given CloudWatch Logs permission to ex ecute your function.
    at Request.extractError 

......

(/mnt/******/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) message: 'Could not execute the lambda function. Make sure you have given CloudWatch Logs permission to execute your function.',   code: 'InvalidParameterException',   time: 2019-03-21T03:05:47.966Z,   requestId: '39c9******3',   statusCode: 400,  retryable: false,   retryDelay: ******86 } InvalidParameterException: Could not execute the lambda function. Make sure you have given CloudWatch Logs permission to execute your function.
```

supplement：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Iv7.jpg)

I gave these executive roles：

```
  AWSLambdaFullAccess
  CloudWatchFullAccess
  CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
  AmazonVPCFullAccess
  AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
  AWSLambdaRole




{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutSubscriptionFilter",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = {
Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction', /* required */
FunctionName: 'arn:aws:lambda:******:******:function:******', /* required */
Principal: 'logs.*region*.amazonaws.com', /* required */
StatementId: '******', /* required */
// SourceAccount: '******',
// SourceArn: 'arn:aws:logs:::******:******'
};

lambda.addPermission(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need in the role policy for having CloudWatch Full Access.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the docs, you need to grant permission to CloudWatch Logs the right to execute your Lambda function.

To perform this task, you can use this CLI command:

> aws lambda add-permission --function-name "lamda1" --statement-id
> "lamda1"  --principal "logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" --action
> "lambda:InvokeFunction"  --source-arn
> "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxxxx047983:log-group:testgroup:*"
> --source-account "xxxxxx047983"

Make sure you replace the function name with your function name and replace the xxxxxx with your account details. For more information, see the [Amazon CloudWatch Logs Guide](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html).